# Why is the temperature of a black hole given by $T=E/2S$?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, entropy, hawking-radiation

Naively, I would imagine that
$$
 T = \frac{E}{S}
$$
However, for a black hole, $E=c^4 R / 2G$ and $S= A k c^3 / 4 G \hbar $, which yields
$$
 T = \frac{E}{2S}
$$
Is there a simple explanation for the factor 2?

Comment: Why would you think the first statement should be true?

Comment: How does your comment help explaining the factor 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple explanation for the factor 2?

Yes. This is a consequence of a purely mathematical fact called [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity). For (nonrotating and uncharged) black holes  the [first law of black hole mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#The_First_Law) could be written as
$$
dM = T dA,
$$
But since the mass $M$ of a black hole is a homogeneous function of degree $\frac 12 $ in area $A$, the mass could be expressed as a bilinear form:
$$
M = 2 \, T A .
$$
This relationship could also be generalized to include angular momentum $J$ and electric charge $Q$:
$$
 M = 2\, T A+2\,\Omega J+ \Phi Q,
$$
where $\Omega$ is the angular velocity and $\Phi$ is electromagnetic potential at the horizon (there is no $2$ in the last term). This formula is known as [Smarr relation](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.30.71).